# i'm a complete noob over React and i don't understand why we need react build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

It's been a couple of weeks since I started working on React. I'm having fun with it. What's the point of React Build? To create a full-stack application, you make a NodeJS/express back-end and a front-end in separate folders. My booking website is finally done. When it comes to deploying it, why can't I upload the folders like I have on my local machine? It's both on different ports and in different folders. why did i waste my time on cors if everything was going to be on single port ???

why ? react Build ?

Comment: Because react code is in its own weird language called JSX and not javascript and the browser does not understand JSX? You are always building React, even when developing code. Or are you asking why you need to `build` instead of `start`?

Answer (score 1):

You could actually upload same files and folders of react you have on your local machine and serve all of that to customer and it will work as usual. The issue would be performance. You will have to server so many files and folders together plus all the packages. What react build does is using the bundler, put everything together in one build folder and only serve that. Build folder is as minimized as possible with all the packages needed to run application. Hope that answers your question